# Symfony2 Doctrine ManyToMany relationship not reconized

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, relationships

I'm trying to create a ManyToMany relationship. Here's the code:

Article.php

```
namespace Heitor\ProjetoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text")
     */
    protected $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="articles")
     */
    protected $author;

    /*
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles_tags")
     */
    protected $tags;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set text
     *
     *
     * @param string $text
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setText($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get text
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param \Heitor\ProjetoBundle\Entity\Author $author
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAuthor(\Heitor\ProjetoBundle\Entity\Author $author = null)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return \Heitor\ProjetoBundle\Entity\Author 
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }
}
```

Tag.php

```
namespace Heitor\ProjetoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    protected $articles;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Add articles
     *
     * @param \Heitor\ProjetoBundle\Entity\Article $articles
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function addArticle(\Heitor\ProjetoBundle\Entity\Article $articles)
    {
        $this->articles[] = $articles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove articles
     *
     * @param \Heitor\ProjetoBundle\Entity\Article $articles
     */
    public function removeArticle(\Heitor\ProjetoBundle\Entity\Article $articles)
    {
        $this->articles->removeElement($articles);
    }

    /**
     * Get articles
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getArticles()
    {
        return $this->articles;
    }
}
```

The methods on each class were auto-generated via the command `doctrine:generate:entites`, I just did the attributes and mappings beforehand.

Then when I try to create the tables with `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` it doesn't try to create the `articles_tags` relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE Tag (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Author (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Article (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, author_id INT DEFAULT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, text LONGTEXT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_CD8737FAF675F31B (author_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Article ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CD8737FAF675F31B FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES Author (id);
```

Why doesn't it try to create the `addTag` & etc. methods on Article.php? And why it doesn't try to create the ManyToMany joinTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding join columns? Maybe it helps.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="articles")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles_tags",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
 protected $tags;
```

Also, it seems you have added the tags later and forgot to call the generate entities again because I can't find getters and setters for tags in your code. Try to run the `doctrine:generate:entites` again.

Lastly, have you checked that your database doesn't already have that table present? (This shouldn't be possible, but it doesn't hurt to check if you don't have any other ideas.)

Comment: Just tried adding join columns, same behavior. I tried running `doctrine:generate:entities` again, and it still doesn't create the methods for tags (ex: `addTag`). That is the point: for some reason it doesn't reconize $tags as a relationship, so it doesn't create methods and it doesn't try to create the table.

Comment: Try doing the validating: `doctrine:schema:validate`. Please post your results.

Comment: Oh, you're missing the starting comment double star... `/**` instead of `/*`. That must be the culprit! I was missing it as well, just performed the edit.

Comment: No way! That worked. Thanks, Symfony annotation parser!